# "I saw you see me"

Tags: meaning

In my text book, I saw this sentence, "I saw you see me." I felt so strange about this. However, after thinking hard, I finally got the answer. My answer was "You can't see the past things right now".

Is my interpretation right? I need some answers from native English speakers.

Comment: Doubtful. *I saw you see me* means that I noticed that you looked at me.

Comment: Unfortunately I don’t think that’s right.  “I saw you see me” most likely means that at the moment when you saw me, I saw you looking at me but you most likely did not know that I saw you.

Comment: Probably, the following sounds better - "I saw you looking at me" or "I noticed you looking at me" or  on the lighter side "I caught you looking/ ogling at me"

Comment: Your sentence is grammatically correct but simply does not make sense well. I would say "I saw you seeing me" instead.

Comment: @Abbasi "I saw you seeing me." isn't quite right. "I saw you looking at me." is how it would usually be said.

Comment: @ColleenV: Of course. I din't want to change the basic arrangement of their sentence, so I went for the possible one I could make using it. If I were told to make a good one from the beginning, well, I would certainly state something else. Your one is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I believe an alternative (albeit fairly dry) way to say what is being expressed here would be:

> I noticed that you could see me.

As others have mentioned in the comments, it seems that the author is trying to express to the person they are talking to that at some previous point in time, they were aware of that person looking at them. To give much more in the way of interpretation is quite difficult without some context for that past event.

Comment: Also,  we could turn your example around a little and say "I saw you notice me."